# Weird rounding using numpy.floor() to every 0.02

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, rounding

I'm having trouble working out how to round some data up to every 0.02. Here's my code:

```
def cpt_rnd(x):
    return np.floor(x*50)/50

x = np.array([32.16, 32.18, 32.2, 32.22])

d = cpt_rnd(x)
print(d)
```

Which returns:

```
[32.14, 32.18, 32.2,  32.22]
```

And is missing the 32.16 - it has been rounded down to 32.14

I'm noticing similar behaviour in both ceil and floor not returning the correct answer. Here's the output using `np.ceil` instead

```
[32.16, 32.18, 32.22, 32.22]
```

In this example there should be a 32.2 then 32.22, instead 32.22 is repeated. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens due to the finite resolution of floating-point numbers on a computer leading to slightly inaccurate results when you perform arithmetic operations on them ([Roundoff error caused by floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error#Roundoff_error_caused_by_floating-point_arithmetic)). You can see what happens by just performing the parts of your algorithm separately:

```py
>>> 32.16*50
1607.9999999999998
```

So you see this is slightly off from the exactly accurate result of `1608.0` and will result in `1607.0` after applying `np.floor()`.

What you could do to fix this is put a `np.round()` inside the `np.floor()` call, i.e.:

```py
def cpt_rnd(x):
    return np.floor(np.round(x*50))/50
```

By default, `np.round()` rounds off to the nearest integer, which is exactly what we want here.

Comment: Yep that did it! Thanks